# Erro de renderização da fonte Code128

Tags: pdf, genexus, código-de-barras

Desenvolvi um relatório em Genexus X Ev1 que necessita imprimir o código de barras utilizando a fonte Code128. Esta compilado em `.NET`.

No ambiente de desenvolvimento (**Windows 2012**) tudo funciona perfeitamente. O problema está no servidor de produção (**Windows 2008**). Na impressão do pdf no lugar da imagem aparecem números.

Tentei reinstalar a fonte no servidor de produção e aparentemente esta ok. Porém a impressão/renderização do pdf em qualquer navegador esta errada.

Alguma sugestão sobre outras configurações que eu devo verificar?

Comment: A sugestão seria não usar fonte para gerar barras. Apesar da comodidade, código de barras são tão simples que não custa nada desenhar certinho diretamente pela aplicação (em especial o C128). Se vai realmente insistir na fonte e não quer problemas, precisa fazer o _embed_ dela no PDF, não basta disponibilizar na máquina. Mas tenha a certeza que embed de fonte de barras é sempre uma solução de segunda categoria, para não dizer outra coisa.

Comment: O Genexus tem um arquivo de configuração que se encarrega de fazer o embeed da fonte ao gerar o pdf conforme comentado abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Para que o usuário visualize a fonte corretamente, a fonte deve estar no computador dele, não no servidor.

Se você vai servir um PDF como elemento de página, a única solução coesa é gerar a imagem correspondente.

Com a fonte no servidor, você pode gerar a imagem com as bibliotecas gráficas do framework, i.e.:

```
string nomeDaSuaFonte = "eu não sei o nome de família dela, mas você pode descobrir. Substituia por este texto.";
var fontFamily = new FontFamily(nomeDaSuaFonte);
var font = new Font(fontFamily, 32, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
var solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

var bitmap = new Bitmap(largura, altura); // Monte conforme suas necessidades
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

graphics.DrawString("seu código de barras aqui", font, solidBrush, new PointF(10, 60));
```

Você também pode gerar um PDF no servidor. Existem várias bibliotecas para isso. Se estiver a usar MVC, sugiro o uso de [Rotativa](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rotativa). Você ainda precisa gerar o código de barras como uma imagem, como acima, mas ao menos você garante que o usuário tem acesso a um PDF com o código de barras renderizado corretamente.

Comment: O Genexus gera o código c#. Eu não tenho acesso direto ao código fonte gerado.

Answer (score 0):

Rubem,

Compare as versões do arquivo PDFReport.ini do servidor de desenvolvimento, com o de produção, mais especificamente na seção [EmbeedFonts].

Mais informações: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?27500,PDFReport.ini+file+format,

https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?S,,,19666;;

Nesse arquivo também existe uma tag para geração de códigos de barras como imagem: Barcode128AsImage. Teria que ver se na X Ev. 1 funciona, pois não encontrei referências sobre versão do Gx.

Comment: Cheguei a essa conclusão lógica, porém o problema é que mesmo colocando eles idênticos não funciona no servidor de produção.